# How to use local_seq in the design document of couchdb database?

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I am new to Couchdb and I am trying to pull the data from Couchdb incrementally. A sequence number from source will definitely help me. I added

```
"options": {
   "local_seq": true
},
```

in the design document. Is that the proper usage of the 'options' field in the design document? I want to see the local_seq field the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#View_Generation_Options), you need to define the option on the design document. Once it's defined, you can use the _local_seq as a document property. As I have defined in my mapping function, I emit the keys with the value of their _local_seq.

Have you try this :

```
{
  "_id": "_design/global",
  "language": "javascript",
  "views": {
    "byAge": {
      "map": "function(doc){if(doc.age)emit(doc._id,doc._local_seq);}"
    }
  },
 "options": {
            "local_seq": true
          }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this too, but result is the same. I still can't see the sequence number.

Comment: @Nikhil I have updated my answer. I have tested it and it works perfectly. Give it a try and accept my answer if it helped you!

Comment: should be emit(doc._id,doc._local_seq) instead of emit(doc._id,doc._local_sec). please update